# how to add key and a value to a json using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, json

i have a json variable like this

```
var jsondata={"all":"true"}
```

i want to push another key and value to the jsondata. after that my jsondata have to be like this.

```
{"all":"true","FDamount":"false","DDamount":"true"}
```

how to do that??? i tried jsondata.push({"FDamount":"false"}) and jsondata.push("FDamount:false"). both of these method is not working.

thank you

Comment: You do not seem to use JSON anywhere? Those are just simple object literals (and no arrays, btw)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like this

```
jsondata.FDamount = 'false';
// or
jsondata['FDamount'] = 'false';
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply do this :

```
jsondata['FDamount'] = 'false';
jsondata['DDamount'] = 'true';
```

Or this :

```
jsondata.FDamount = 'false';
jsondata.DDamount = 'true';
```

By the way, you define boolean as string, the correct way should be :

```
jsondata['FDamount'] = false;
jsondata['DDamount'] = true;
```

To push a little bit further, you can use jQuery.extend to extend the original var, like this :

```
jQuery.extend(jsondata, {'FDamount': 'false', 'DDamount': 'true'});
// Now, jsondata will be :
{"all":"true","FDamount":"false","DDamount":"true"}
```

[jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is available when using jQuery (of course), but I'm sure you can find similar methods in other libraries/frameworks.

(I'm using single quotes, but double quotes works too)

Comment: How can i do that for each element? I need add new key and value for each element.

Comment: What do you mean by "each element" ?

Comment: "Each element" is each item when parse to an object your Json Data you can see items. I want add an key with value for each item in your Json structure.